# Does the 2011 Mac Mini work with dual monitors?

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I want to start development on Mac, and from what I read around, everyone suggests the current Mac Mini. So my question is, does the hardware support dual monitors out of the box?

If not, what should I purchase to get a dual monitor setup working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I too am a developer using a mid-2011 Mac Mini (with AMD Radeon GPU) connected to two Samsung displays

- one display connected using HDMI cable which comes with the Mac Mini, and
- another display connected using an Apple DisplayPort to VGA cable which I
  had to buy separately.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html

> Extended desktop and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports up to 1920 by 1200 pixels on a DVI or VGA display; up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on a **dual-link DVI** display using Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter (sold separately)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - search for the term "[two displays](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=two%20displays%20mac%20mini%20site%3aapple.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" at the [marketing page for the Mac Mini](http://www.apple.com/macmini/features.html).